# setcookie() not working on my website, same works on phpfiddle & w3schools

Tags: php, cookies

Unable to set cookie using php 'setcookie' on my website.

Its the basic code I got from w3schools. It works on w3schools (the example works on my browser), also works on phpfiddle, but just won't work on my website, no matter how many times I refresh. Here's the exact code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$cookie_name = "user3";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value); // 86400 = 1 day


if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This exact same code works when I put it on phpfiddle. But doesn't work on my website..

Also, when I try to set a cookie with JavaScript - it works fine.

Comment: This question should not be tagged with [javascript] as it has nothing to do with Javascript

Comment: @jbman223 oh sorry, I inadvertently added JS.. unable to remove the tag now. Maybe mods can help

Comment: I've approved the pending edit to remove the tag. As an aside, you should've been getting an error along the lines of "Headers already sent" when making the call. Not the most useful error message, but if you weren't seeing it then make sure you've got logging enabled (or are displaying errors to the user) and that you can actually see the errors as they come up - it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @Basic I wasn't.. thanks, will certainly make life a lot easier when coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to place the code

```
$cookie_name = "user3";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value);
```

above the html content i.e

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

It helps to understand the underlying mechanism for cookies being set here.  Cookies are only set in the response header to the request (outside of using javascript cookie setting techniques, that is).  A `setcookie()` call, in fac,t is just a convenience function that abstracts the programmer away from having to manually set the response headers related to cookies.

Since headers can ONLY be sent prior to any of the actual HTTP response content being sent, you MUST perform any `setcookie()` calls (just like any `header()` calls) prior to sending any of the response body.

In your case, you send several lines of HTML before calling `setcookie()`, meaning the header containing the cookie will never be sent, as it is already too late in the the response cycle.  You need to move this code before any output you are making to the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You see, here -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_cookie1, w3schools puts the code after the doctype. I used that exact same code & it didn't work..

Comment: @user3001859 Among programming community, W3Schools is generally known as a horrible resource from which to learn proper coding. Take anything you get from there with a heaping spoon of salt.